# Sum previous date values to today Date

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I want to calculate the previous date values to current date and so. Here is my script.

- I already fetched previous day stock value for initial prevDayStock ie  `let prevStock = 21`

```
let prevStock = 21; 
let stocksArr= [
  { date: '2021-06-30',stock: 4 },
  { date: '2021-07-01',stock: 5 },
  { date: '2021-07-02',stock: 2 },
  { date: '2021-07-03',stock: 1 },
  { date: '2021-07-04', stock: 5 },
  { date: '2021-07-05',stock: 3 },
  { date: '2021-07-06', stock: 4 },
  { date: '2021-07-07',stock: 1 },
  { date: '2021-07-08', stock: 4 }
]

stocksArr.reduce((acc, cur, idx, arr) => {
  const prod = idx === 0 ? 0 : arr[idx - 1].stock;
  const value = acc + cur.stock + prod;
  cur.stock = acc;
  return value;
}, prevStock); 
  console.log(stocksArr)
```

Expected results:

```
    [{ date: '2021-06-30',stock: 21 },
      { date: '2021-07-01',stock: 24 },
      { date: '2021-07-02',stock: 29 },
      { date: '2021-07-03',stock: 31 },
      { date: '2021-07-04', stock: 32 },
      { date: '2021-07-05',stock: 37 },
      { date: '2021-07-06', stock: 40 },
      { date: '2021-07-07',stock: 44 },
      { date: '2021-07-08', stock: 45 }]
```

What is right solution to resolve it.

```js
let prevStock = 21;
let stocksArr= [
  { date: '2021-06-30',stock: 4 },
  { date: '2021-07-01',stock: 5 },
  { date: '2021-07-02',stock: 2 },
  { date: '2021-07-03',stock: 1 },
  { date: '2021-07-04', stock: 5 },
  { date: '2021-07-05',stock: 3 },
  { date: '2021-07-06', stock: 4 },
  { date: '2021-07-07',stock: 1 },
  { date: '2021-07-08', stock: 4 }
]

stocksArr.reduce((acc, cur, idx, arr) => {
  const prod = idx === 0 ? 0 : arr[idx - 1].stock;
  const value = acc + cur.stock + prod;
  cur.stock = acc;
  return value;
}, prevStock); 
  console.log(stocksArr)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want cumulative results, here is the answer

```js
    var stocksArr= [
      { date: '2021-06-30',stock: 4 },
      { date: '2021-07-01',stock: 5 },
      { date: '2021-07-02',stock: 2 },
      { date: '2021-07-03',stock: 1 },
      { date: '2021-07-04', stock: 5 },
      { date: '2021-07-05',stock: 3 },
      { date: '2021-07-06', stock: 4 },
      { date: '2021-07-07',stock: 1 },
      { date: '2021-07-08', stock: 4 }
    ]
    
var result = stocksArr.reduce(function(r, a) {
  if (r.length > 0)
    a.stock += r[r.length - 1];
  r.push(a.stock);
  a['sum'] = a.stock
  return r;
}, [21]); // <-- pass intialValue to here

    
    console.log(stocksArr)
```

```
    [
  {
    "date": "2021-06-30",
    "stock": 25,
    "sum": 25
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-07-01",
    "stock": 30,
    "sum": 30
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-07-02",
    "stock": 32,
    "sum": 32
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-07-03",
    "stock": 33,
    "sum": 33
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-07-04",
    "stock": 38,
    "sum": 38
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-07-05",
    "stock": 41,
    "sum": 41
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-07-06",
    "stock": 45,
    "sum": 45
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-07-07",
    "stock": 46,
    "sum": 46
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-07-08",
    "stock": 50,
    "sum": 50
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer. same Accumulation values should place in respective dates.

Comment: SO expects the same object array back. Watch when you reduce, that the original object array is not mutated

Comment: @mplungjan it has to take my initialised values which `let prevStock = 21;`

Comment: @underscore  `a= a.stock`; this will work instead of ` a["sum"] = a.stock`. I want notify you that my initial value is `let prevStock = 21;` it has to be consider first results

Comment: @Jay please check the updated code. you can simply pass intialValue to reducer function after callback